# dynamically generate an email template based on a page layout?

Tags: force.com, email-template

we use a lot of email templates for notifying different teams in our org, which creates a lot of overhead in updating the email templates when ever a new field is added. Is there an app out there, or something, that you can use to create the templates for you?

I am looking at the html of the page layout and copying and pasting it that way, but the limitation on that is you get the field values, not their API name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see two possible options you might want to consider for approaching this problem, both involve utilising the [Visualforce form of Email Templates](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/VisualForceEmailTemplates_sample). Once you select this type of email template, you can utilise the [apex:detail](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm) tag to render as per the Page Layout or utilise [Field Sets](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) to add new fields or columns to existing templates by simply [editing a designated Field Set](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_editing_field_sets.htm&language=en_US) on the related objects.

Comment: Hey Andy! Thanks for the tip. My initial thought is I want to stay away from a VF solution, since my BA wouldn't be able to update them. It turns into a scalability issue at that point in my head. Or does this approach bypass that?

Comment: Yes it does to some degree, since your BA can access the Field Sets from the Custom Object definition under the Setup menu, no need to go into the Visualforce markup once the VF page has been taught to respond to them.